# OpenGL ES VertexArray and not drawing properly on android

Tags: android, opengl-es, vertex-buffer

I'm working on a little game demo using OpenGL ES 1 and using a "BufferPool", which essentially is just a fancy interface for a direct ByteBuffer which I store all the vertex, color, and texcoord data in. I'm having some issues getting it to draw properly. I must be setting up the opengl state wrong, but I'm fairly new to OpenGL and can't tell what it is. I'd appreciate any help muchly :)

code: http://pastebin.com/bw3eM0TW

I've put it up on pastebin as there's a fair amount of code related to the BufferPool and rendering.

Comment: What is your expected and actual output? Are you seeing any logcat output? Do you have the same vertices and the same projection working elsewhere in a known working environment? If you eliminate the BufferPool and just draw directly in onDrawFrame does it render correctly?

Comment: Expected output is a square drawing at the top left (in portrait mode), actual was nothing. Definitely seeing my logcat output. Turns out though that my math for the offsets and pool positions was all wrong. so basically the setVertex/setColor type methods in my pool/object classes were writing to the wrong places. there isn't a way I can give you karma for answering is there?

Comment: Glad you got it figured out. I think you'd need more rep yourself to vote up a comment. If I had answered as an "answer" then you could.  No worries -- we'll call this a freebie ;)  Upvotes for linking your code in the first place and for answering your own problem in the comment.